# python: Type Error while iterating over list consisting of tuples with a for-loop

Tags: python

i'm doing this assignment for school where I have to build a "game". The point of the game is to shoot a rocket into space in a certain way that it will hit a target  on the other side of the screen. The rocket has to go around planets and such and has to take their gravitational force into account... However I dont know what I'm doing wrong here:

```
planet1 = (vector(position1_x,position1_y), mass1)
planet2=...
planets = [planet1,planet2,planet3]
position_rocket = vector(positionrocket_x, positionrocket_y)

def gravforce(m,a,b):
    #a = position_planet, b = position_rocket, m = mass planet
   r = b-a
   return (-G * m/mag2(r)))) * norm(r)
   #this is just a formula to calculate the gravitational force produced by one planet


def total_gravforce(planets,position_rocket):
     total_grav = vector(0,0,0)
     for elements in len(planets):
         total_grav = total_grav + gravforce(planets[elements][1],planets[elements][0],position_rocket)
    return total_grav
```

As a result I get this: 
for elements in len(planets):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Thanks

Comment: Should it just be `for planet in planets:`

Comment: change to `range(len(planets))`

Comment: @depperm please don't recommend that. It's not Pythonic and there is almost always a better way of doing it.

Comment: I realize there are better ways to do that, but based on his current code, this would make the loop work, not the best way but working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you're not iterating over a list of tuples, you're operating over `len()` which returns an integer. Don't do that.

You probably meant to use `range`, but don't do that either: you should always iterate over the list itself, which gives you the elements directly:

```
for elements in planets:
    total_grav = total_grav + gravforce(elements[1], elements[0], position_rocket)
```

Comment: Missing a colon but yeah.

Comment: @Tagc sorry, fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much! this fixed my problem!

Comment: @IDontLikeThisAssignment You should accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

since your trying to iterate through the length of planets (which is an int) you're not getting the results that you're expecting.

try changing the following:

```
 for elements in len(planets):
     total_grav = total_grav + gravforce(planets[elements][1],planets[elements][0],position_rocket)
```

to

```
 for elements in planets:
     total_grav = total_grav + gravforce(elements[1],elements[0],position_rocket)
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Good try, but there are other things to change in the code then ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how does this look now?

Comment: well, that's better but now it's just a duplicate of Daniel Roseman's answer <g>